# Pass URL into query string and read from c# code behind

Tags: c#, html, url

I have html link which contain navigation URL like "https://mysiteURL.com/logout.aspx?ReturnUrl=https://www.yoursite.com/"

Now functionality should be like when user click on above mention link it should redirect to logout page and then system will clear all session for user and redirect to “ReturnUrl “ value in our case it is https://www.yoursite.com.

Issue is when I try to read “ReturnUrl” from query sting it always return null value. My code behind is look like below.

```
if (Request["ReturnUrl"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["ReturnUrl"]))
{
     Response.Redirect(Request["ReturnUrl"],true);
}
```

Can anyone give the solution this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you would want to use `Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]` instead of looking directly at `Request["ReturnUrl"]`.

Comment: I believe both are the same please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1 for your reference.